# How to add a map in to get the data in the firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my collection of orders and how can I display all of the data in the order array? Like how can I map it through and how can I also display the document ID?

[image]

this is my codes for fetching the data in the firestore:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firestore
      .collection("orders")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const orders = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          users.push({
            ...orders
          });
        });
        this.setState({ users: users });
        // console.log(snapshot)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure which `documentID` you are referring to. The `documentID` in the element of the `order` Array for each doc or the document ID of each order document as shown on the screenshot?

The following will loop over all the documents in the `orders` collection, then, for each doc, it will loop over each `orderItem` (each element of the `orderItems` Array). You may adapt it to fit your exact needs.

```
  firestore
    .collection('orders')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const orders = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

        // Update following your comment
        // If you want to get the ID of the order document, do as follows
        const orderDocID = doc.id;            

        const data = doc.data();
        data.order.orderItems.forEach((item) => {
          orders.push(item.documentID);
        });
      });
      this.setState({ orders: orders });
    });
```

---

If you want to add more data to the order item (according to your last comment), do as follows:

```
  firestore
    .collection('orders')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const orders = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const orderDocID = doc.id;            
        const data = doc.data();
        data.order.orderItems.forEach((item) => {
          const orderObj = {
              documentID: item.documentID,
              productImg: item.productImg,
              productName: item.productName,
          }
          orders.push(orderObj);
        });
      });
      this.setState({ orders: orders });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this. I was referring to that document ID, the one at the very top.

Comment: Than you, It did work. I can already map it and it display on the screen. How can I label each of the data? This is how I mapped it:                             
    {this.state.orders.map((item, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            ))}

Comment: See the update. You need to use the id property. (This answers your first comment)

Comment: "How can I label each of the data?" => What do you exactly mean? Which data item you want to use as label?

Comment: like labe; it as shown in the picture with the documentID,productImg, and productName

Comment: I'm really sorry for this, just one question more, how would I get the data inside the array "order" but it's not included in the orderItems?

Comment: I mean do I have to create another componentDidMount?

Comment: Data in the `order` field (which is a map) can be obtained by `snapshot.forEach((doc) => {const oder = doc.data().order ...});`